data filtering based on dateRangeInput()
I have two data frames "df" and "df2". I want data of the "df" to be rearranged as the "df2" by a selected date range in dateRangeInput(). However, it is simply not working. I cannot figure out what is wrong with the script below.
I think, the following interconnected two parts of the whole code have to be reviewed, namely:
The 1st part:
observe({
  if (!is.null(input$dates) && length(input$dates) == 4 && !any(is.na(input$dates))) {
     selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1], format = "%d.%m.%Y"), 
                           as.Date(input$dates[2], format = "%d.%m.%Y"), by = "day")
     data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates, ]
     } else {
    selected_dates2 <- character(0)
    data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates2, ]
    }
 })

and, the 2nd Part:
    output$Trial1_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$df2, stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
            hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
    })

Here is the whole code:
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

df <- data.table(
    dasa = as.character(c("03.01.2000", "04.01.2000", "05.01.2000", "03.02.2000", "10.02.2000",     "25.03.2000")),
    nasa = as.numeric(c(23, 32, 34, 43, 51, 15)),
    casa = as.character(c("abc123", "bcd123", "fgh808", "abc123", "cde909", "fgh303")),
    stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

ui <- dashboardPage(
    dashboardHeader(title = "Financial Statements of Uzbekistan"),
    dashboardSidebar(
        menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
        menuItem("Accounting", tabName = "Recognition",
                 menuSubItem("item1", tabName = "Item1")
        )
     ),
    dashboardBody(
        tabItems(
            tabItem(
                tabName = "Item1",
                fluidRow(
                    column(
                        width = 6,
                        "Trial1_col1",
                        rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item1")
                    ),
                    column(
                        width = 6,
                        "Trial1_col2",
                        selectInput("choices", "Choose an option:",
                                    choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
                        uiOutput("nested_ui")
                    ),
                    column(
                        width = 6,
                        "Trial1_col3",
                        rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item2")
                    )
                )
            )
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    data <- reactiveValues()

    observe({
        data$df <- as.data.frame(df)
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item1))
            data$df <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item1)
    })

    observe({
        if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item2))
            data$df2 <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item2)
    })

observe({
  if (!is.null(input$dates) && length(input$dates) == 4 && !any(is.na(input$dates))) {
     selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1], format = "%d.%m.%Y"), 
                           as.Date(input$dates[2], format = "%d.%m.%Y"), by = "day")
     data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates, ]
     } else {
    selected_dates2 <- character(0)
    data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates2, ]
    }
 })

    output$Trial1_Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$df, stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
            hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
    })

    output$nested_ui <- renderUI({
        if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
            dateRangeInput("dates", "Select a date range:", format = "dd.mm.yyyy")
        } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
            textInput("text", "Enter some text:")
        }
    })

    output$Trial1_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
        rhandsontable(data$df2, stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
            hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
    })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Why do you do length(input$dates) == 4 in the if condition? It shouldn't be 2 instead of 4?

Stephane, I have tried  with 2, but got the error in seq.int: incorrect sign of argument by. Fortunately, 4 does not give such an error, though df2 is not reacting to dateRangeInput() anyway.

Perhaps your date format is the issue.  You can try using YYYY-MM-DD format dates.  Try this
library(data.table)
library(shiny)
library(shinydashboard)
library(rhandsontable)

df <- data.table(
  dasa = as.character(c("03.01.2000", "04.01.2000", "05.01.2000", "03.02.2000", "10.02.2000", "25.03.2000")),
  nasa = as.numeric(c(23, 32, 34, 43, 51, 15)),
  casa = as.character(c("abc123", "bcd123", "fgh808", "abc123", "cde909", "fgh303")),
  stringsAsFactors = FALSE
)

cc <- strsplit(df$dasa,".",fixed=TRUE)
d <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-2]
m <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))-1]
y <- unlist(cc)[3*(1:length(df$dasa))]
df$das <- paste0(y,"-",m,"-",d)

ui <- dashboardPage(
  dashboardHeader(title = "Financial Statements of Uzbekistan"),
  dashboardSidebar(
    menuItem("Home", tabName = "home"),
    menuItem("Accounting", tabName = "Recognition",
             menuSubItem("item1", tabName = "Item1")
    )
  ),
  dashboardBody(
    tabItems(
      tabItem(
        tabName = "Item1",
        fluidRow(
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col1",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item1")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col2",
            selectInput("choices", "Choose an option:",
                        choices = c("choice 1", "choice 2")),
            uiOutput("nested_ui")
          ),
          column(
            width = 6,
            "Trial1_col3",
            rHandsontableOutput("Trial1_Item2")
          )
        )
      )
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  data <- reactiveValues()

  observe({
    data$df <- as.data.frame(df)
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item1))
      data$df <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item1)
  })

  observe({
    if (!is.null(input$Trial1_Item2))
      data$df2 <- hot_to_r(input$Trial1_Item2)
  })

  observe({

    if (!is.null(input$dates)) { # && length(input$dates) == 4 && !any(is.na(input$dates))) {
      selected_dates <- seq(as.Date(input$dates[1]),
                            as.Date(input$dates[2]), by = "day")
      data$df2 <- df[as.Date(df$das) %in% selected_dates, ]

    } else {
      selected_dates2 <- character(0)
      data$df2 <- df[df$dasa %in% selected_dates2, ]
    }
  })

  output$Trial1_Item1 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
  })

  output$nested_ui <- renderUI({
    if (input$choices == "choice 1") {
      dateRangeInput("dates", "Select a date range:", format = "dd.mm.yyyy",
                     start = "2000-01-01", end = "2000-03-31")
    } else if (input$choices == "choice 2") {
      textInput("text", "Enter some text:")
    }
  })

  output$Trial1_Item2 <- renderRHandsontable({
    rhandsontable(data$df2[,c(1:3)], stretchH = "all", rowHeaderWidth = 50, height = 300) |>
      hot_col(1, format = "%d.%m.%Y", type = "date")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)


Dear YBS, thanks for solution. Your approach is perfect. But I wanted the date format to be dd.mm.yyyy. I have tried it by making some changes in your part of script, but did not succeed. Is there any way to handle it?

Your date format is maintained in "dasa" column.  A new column named "das" keeps the format to work with which does not need to be displayed in the table

Dear YBS, it worked well. Appreciate! Thanks for you time and efforts.
